# VBA macro - searches through a filtered table, stops when entry passes criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have written several subs which are then called from a main sub. Individual subs run very quickly, most are instantaneous (the DoFind sub takes a few seconds to run due to the large amounts of data in the table) however when I run the main sub it takes up to a minute to execute. Any ideas/tips on why this is the case?

Note, I haven't had much experience with VBA (all has been learnt in the past week). There are other macros used, but they are not shown since even the test sub takes approximately 1 minute

```
Sub DoFind()

    Dim i As Long

    i = 1

        Do While Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value <> Empty

                Dim BearingArray(6) As String


                BearingArray(0) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value
                BearingArray(1) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "B").Value
                BearingArray(2) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "C").Value
                BearingArray(3) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "D").Value
                BearingArray(4) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "E").Value
                BearingArray(5) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "F").Value
                BearingArray(6) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "G").Value


                With Sheets("Calculations")
                    .Cells(17, "K").Value = BearingArray(0)
                    .Cells(19, "O").Value = BearingArray(1)
                    .Cells(20, "O").Value = BearingArray(2)
                    .Cells(23, "O").Value = BearingArray(3)
                    .Cells(22, "O").Value = BearingArray(4)
                    .Cells(26, "O").Value = BearingArray(5)
                    .Cells(17, "L").Value = BearingArray(6)
                End With

                i = i + 1

                    If Sheets("Calculations").Cells(17, "M").Value = "PASS" Then
        Exit Do
                    Else
                    End If
        Loop
                    If Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value = Empty Then
                        MsgBox "No available bearing."


                    End If


End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Create_Sheet_Temp()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Temp" 

' This creates a new worksheet called "Temp"

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Copy_Paste()

    Dim NewTable As ListObject
    Sheets("Calculations").Activate

    Set NewTable = Sheets("Calculations").ListObjects("Full_Bearings_List")

    NewTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    NewTable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("Temp").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

        'This sub copies all visible cells from a filtered table and pastes them to the new sheet called "Temp" 

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub test()
    Create_Sheet_Temp
    Copy_Paste
    DoFind

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Code Review. Could you expand a bit on the context your code runs in and what it does? What problem is it trying to solve? What are your Inputs & Desired Outputs? Do you have control over the format of your input data or are there restrictions you have to work with?

Comment: It will also be **impossible** to tell why your main sub is slow if we can't actually see it. If you want it reviewed and improved, then we need to see the code for it.

Comment: Please, feel free to paste **all** the code. The more we can see, the more we can make specific recommendations for your situation and join things up in useful ways.

Comment: @Zak 
 
The 'test' sub is the main sub, and this is the one I am having an issue with. The 'DoFind' sub on its own takes about 6 seconds, and the 'Create_Sheet_Temp' and 'Copy_Paste' subs each take less than 1 second, but when the three are called consecutively in the 'test' sub it takes about 45 seconds to run. I don't understand what could account for such a large time difference, and would appreciate any advice as so far none of the changes I have made (such as using destination instead of copy and paste) have made a noticeable difference to the 'test' sub run-time.

Comment: I edited my answer to add some simple performance improvements.

Comment: It would help to see the formula on the **Calculations** worksheet that may put **PASS** into column M.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I'd just like to say: This is decent code for someone who's brand new to VBA. Great work.

That aside, let's begin:

---

### Option Explicit

If that's not at the top of all your code modules, put it in. Go to Tools --> Options --> Require Variable Declaration to have it auto-inserted into every new module you create.

---

### Easy Performance Improvements

```
Sub DoThing()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .StatusBar = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    ...

    ...

    Code

    ...

    ...

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .StatusBar = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With


End Sub
```

Each of those settings will provide large performance improvements. Especially `ScreenUpdating`. Always check that you're not reliant on the thing you're disabling though. For instance, `DoFind()` is relying on a formula to change, so you shouldn't disable `Calculation`.

---

### Consistent Indenting

Pick an indenting rule and stick to it. Personally, I use a single Tab for each logical level (`If, While, With, etc.`) and it's a widespread convention with VBA. This way, I can easily identify which statements are operating at what level.

Something like this is particularly confusing:

```
               If Sheets("Calculations").Cells(17, "M").Value = "PASS" Then
    Exit Do
               Else
               End If
```

It's much easier to "see" what's going on when it's expressed like this:

```
If Sheets("Calculations").Cells(17, "M").Value = "PASS" Then
    Exit Do
End If
```

I would re-indent your `DoFind` sub like so:

```
Sub DoFind()

    Dim i As Long
    i = 1

    Do While Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value <> Empty

        Dim BearingArray(6) As String
        BearingArray(0) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value
        BearingArray(1) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "B").Value
        BearingArray(2) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "C").Value
        BearingArray(3) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "D").Value
        BearingArray(4) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "E").Value
        BearingArray(5) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "F").Value
        BearingArray(6) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "G").Value

        With Sheets("Calculations")
            .Cells(17, "K").Value = BearingArray(0)
            .Cells(19, "O").Value = BearingArray(1)
            .Cells(20, "O").Value = BearingArray(2)
            .Cells(23, "O").Value = BearingArray(3)
            .Cells(22, "O").Value = BearingArray(4)
            .Cells(26, "O").Value = BearingArray(5)
            .Cells(17, "L").Value = BearingArray(6)
        End With

        i = i + 1

        If Sheets("Calculations").Cells(17, "M").Value = "PASS" Then
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop

    If Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value = Empty Then
        MsgBox "No available bearing."
    End If

End Sub
```

Much easier to follow.

---

### Naming

I recommend the [Excellent, Classic article on naming by Joel spolsky.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)

Naming is, famously, one of the 2 hardest things in software development. It's also one of the most important. Code should be written for other people (including future you) to **understand** as easily and completely as possible.

Names should be **descriptive**, then **unambiguous**, and **only then** concise.
Variables should sound like what they are. I should be able to tell from the name of a Sub/Function **exactly** what it does.

`DoFind`. This tells me **nothing**.

`FindBearing` would be better. I'd offer you an even better name, but there's not enough context to be sure what the rest of your code/workbook is doing and why.

`Create_Sheet_Temp`. Don't use `_` in procedure names. `_` in VBA is used for event triggers e.g. `Workbook_Open` or `Button_OnClick`. Avoid it in your own names to avoid confusion.

`Copy_Paste`. **Useless**. Copy **what?** Paste **what?** Paste **where?**. 
`PasteBearingDataToTempSheet`. Sure, it's a bit verbose, but it's also **useful**. You should always aim for useful names. If you can make them short as well, great, but it's not the priority.

---

### Use the Object Model

The great power of VBA for manipulating MS Office is the extensive Object Model it's integrated with.

There are objects for everything. `Workbook`s, `Worksheet`s, `ListObject`s, `Range`s etc.

---

Take this for instance:

```
        BearingArray(0) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value
        BearingArray(1) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "B").Value
        BearingArray(2) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "C").Value
        BearingArray(3) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "D").Value
        BearingArray(4) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "E").Value
        BearingArray(5) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "F").Value
        BearingArray(6) = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "G").Value
```

What happens if/when your temp sheet has a different name than "Temp"? How about if someone renames the "Calculations" sheet? Not only will your code break, but you'll have to change those strings **everywhere** in your code. Maybe you'll get them all. Maybe you won't. Chances are, it will introduce new errors.

Instead, make some `Worksheet` objects and use those:

```
Sub NewTest()

    Dim tempSheet As Worksheet
    Set tempSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    Dim calculationSheet As Worksheet
    Set calculationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculations")

    PasteBearingDataToTempSheet tempSheet, calculationSheet

    FindBearing tempSheet, calculationSheet

End Sub

Sub PasteBearingDataToTempSheet(ByRef tempSheet As Worksheet, ByRef calculationSheet As Worksheet)

    calculationSheet.Activate

    Dim NewTable As ListObject
    Set NewTable = calculationSheet.ListObjects("Full_Bearings_List")

    NewTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    NewTable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    tempSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'This sub copies all visible cells from a filtered table and pastes them to the new sheet called "Temp"

End Sub

Sub FindBearing(ByRef dataSheet As Worksheet, ByRef calculationSheet As Worksheet)

    Dim i As Long
    i = 1

    Do While dataSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value <> Empty

        Dim BearingArray(6) As String
        With dataSheet
            BearingArray(0) = .Cells(i, "A").Value
            BearingArray(1) = .Cells(i, "B").Value
            BearingArray(2) = .Cells(i, "C").Value
            BearingArray(3) = .Cells(i, "D").Value
            BearingArray(4) = .Cells(i, "E").Value
            BearingArray(5) = .Cells(i, "F").Value
            BearingArray(6) = .Cells(i, "G").Value
        End With

        With calculationSheet
            .Cells(17, "K").Value = BearingArray(0)
            .Cells(19, "O").Value = BearingArray(1)
            .Cells(20, "O").Value = BearingArray(2)
            .Cells(23, "O").Value = BearingArray(3)
            .Cells(22, "O").Value = BearingArray(4)
            .Cells(26, "O").Value = BearingArray(5)
            .Cells(17, "L").Value = BearingArray(6)
        End With

        i = i + 1

        If calculationSheet.Cells(17, "M").Value = "PASS" Then
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop

    If dataSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value = Empty Then
        MsgBox "No available bearing."
    End If

End Sub
```

Now, if either of those names change, you only have to change the declaration in **one** place, and the rest of your code will continue running perfectly. Notice how we don't even have to name the `tempSheet`. We just create it directly into a `worksheet` object.

---

And how about this:

```
        If calculationSheet.Cells(17, "M").Value = "PASS" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
```

What is the significance of the particular cell? How do we know what it's **supposed** to be? And how do we check that it **is** what it's supposed to be?

Depending on your workbook, my first suggestion would be to make that cell a [Named Range](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64).

If we named that cell `"ValidateBearing"` then we could do the following:

```
    Dim validationCell As Range
    Set validationCell = ThisWorkbook.Names("ValidateBearing").RefersToRange

    Const VALIDATION_PASS_TEXT As String = "PASS"

    Do While dataSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value <> Empty

        ...

        ...

        If validationCell.Text = VALIDATION_PASS_TEXT Then
            Exit Do
        End If
```

And now, not only have we made it clear what that cell is and what it's doing, but that cell can now move around as much as it likes. As long as nobody actually deletes the row/column/sheet it's in, that code will always point to the right place.

---

### Other tips & Tricks

---

```
Do While dataSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value <> Empty
```

should be

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(dataSheet.Cells(i, 1))
```

---

```
    If dataSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value = Empty Then
        MsgBox "No available bearing."
    End If
```

This is hacky. Add a proper `Boolean` variable to check for conditions:

```
    Dim foundBearing As Boolean
    foundBearing = False

    Do While Not IsEmpty(dataSheet.Cells(i, 1))

        ...

        ...

        If validationCell.Text = VALIDATION_PASS_TEXT Then
            foundBearing = True
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop

    If Not foundBearing Then
        MsgBox "No available bearing."
    End If
```

---

You can drop `.Select` everywhere and always.

```
A.B.Select
Selection.DoThing
```

Is **always** the same as just doing

```
A.B.DoThing
```

Here:

```
    NewTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    NewTable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

You can drop the first line entirely and it will still run perfectly fine.

---

Get used to using `Sheet.Cells(row, column)` instead of `Sheet.Range("[Address]")`. Not only is it faster, but it's semantically closer to what cells actually are, and you can't do things like this anywhere near as easily with addresses:

```
Dim startRow As Long
startRow = 1

Dim finalRow  As Long
finalRow = [Get final Row]

Dim startColumn As Long
startColumn = 1

Dim finalColumn As Long
finalColumn = [Get final Column]

Dim iRow As Long
Dim iColumn As Long

For iRow = startRow To finalRow
    For iColumn = startColumn To finalColumn

        With [Sheet].Cells(iRow, iColumn)

            [Do Stuff]

        End With

    Next iColumn
Next iRow
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out. All your points make sense and I understand why you should do it the way you say.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the real speed issue is the calculation time and your actual code couldn't work disabling it

in fact there's that

```
    If Sheets("Calculations").Cells(17, "M").Value = "PASS" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
```

inside that

```
Do While Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value <> Empty
```

and `Sheets("Calculations").Cells(17, "M")` isn't set by any statement of your code so I assume that cell holds a formula that must be evaluated at every loop iteration to know if it results in a "PASS" and consequently exit it

**so the real fix would be taking all necessary calculation currently happening in excel UI out of excel cells and porting it inside VBA code**

whether you could succeed in that task or not, there's some code enhancement that can still (after Zak's fine pieces of advice) be made

---

**Avoid unnecessary dimming**

you put

```
Dim BearingArray(6) As String
```

right inside

```
Do While Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value <> Empty
```

while it's not necessary (since all `BearingArray()` elements are set at every itaration) and increases execution time

so to speed things up you want to code like follows

```
Dim i As Long
Dim BearingArray(6) As String '<--| dim it once!

i = 1
Do While Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value <> Empty
```

---

**Avoid unnecessary reading and writing variables**

but you don't even need to pass through any array (`BearingArray()`) to reach your final goal, which is writing into some `Sheets("Calculations")` cells

so that you can avoid both dimming and assigning BearingArray() and directly write into cells like follows:

```
Dim i As Long

i = 1
Do While Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value <> Empty

    With Sheets("Calculations")
        .Cells(17, "K").Value = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value
        .Cells(19, "O").Value = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "B").Value
        .Cells(20, "O").Value = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "C").Value
        .Cells(23, "O").Value = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "D").Value
        .Cells(22, "O").Value = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "E").Value
        .Cells(26, "O").Value = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "F").Value
        .Cells(17, "L").Value = Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "G").Value
    End With
```

and I'd here remind once again that writing into cells and calculating is quite a time consuming activity, so better find a way to take all calculation inside VBA code and leave excel UI just for input and output purposes

---

**Use `With` keyword**

to avoid unnecessary memory accesses, use `With` keyword for multiple reference to the same object

since you have two sheets to reference inside your loop, you can handle one of them with `With` keyword and the other one by setting a `Range` and offsetting from it, like follows:

```
Dim cell As Range, loopRng As Range 

Set loopRng = Sheets("Temp").Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers) '<--| gather all non blank cells of "Temp" sheet column "A" in one Range variable
With Sheets("Calculations") '<--| assume "Calculations" sheet reference once for the whole loop
    For Each cell In loopRng '<--| loop through non blank cells only
        .Cells(17, "K").Value = cell.Offset(, 0).Value '<--| use offset() from cell to get the wanted value
        .Cells(19, "O").Value = cell.Offset(, 1).Value
        .Cells(20, "O").Value = cell.Offset(, 2).Value
        .Cells(23, "O").Value = cell.Offset(, 3).Value
        .Cells(22, "O").Value = cell.Offset(, 4).Value
        .Cells(26, "O").Value = cell.Offset(, 5).Value
        .Cells(17, "L").Value = cell.Offset(, 6).Value
        If .Cells(17, "M").Value = "PASS" Then Exit For
    Next cell
End With
```

this way you also avoid the dimming, initializing and updating of `i` variable

---

**Avoid unnecessary IF statements**

```
If Sheets("Temp").Cells(i, "A").Value = Empty Then
```

can be avoided since you know if you pass the "PASS" check or you don't

so you can code like follows

```
With Sheets("Calculations") '<--| assume "Calculations" sheet reference once for the whole loop
    For Each cell In loopRng '<--| loop through non blank cells only
          ...
          ...
    If .Cells(17, "M").Value = "PASS" Then Exit Sub '<-- directly exit the sub upon passing the check
End With

MsgBox "No available bearing." '<-- once you get here there's no doubt: you didn't PASS
```

---

**Summary**

recapitulating all what above your DoFind() sub would get to

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoFind()
    Dim cell As Range, loopRng As Range '<--define range objects

    Set loopRng = Sheets("Temp").Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers) 
    With Sheets("Calculations") 
        For Each cell In loopRng 
            .Cells(17, "K").Value = cell.Offset(, 0).Value 
            .Cells(19, "O").Value = cell.Offset(, 1).Value
            .Cells(20, "O").Value = cell.Offset(, 2).Value
            .Cells(23, "O").Value = cell.Offset(, 3).Value
            .Cells(22, "O").Value = cell.Offset(, 4).Value
            .Cells(26, "O").Value = cell.Offset(, 5).Value
            .Cells(17, "L").Value = cell.Offset(, 6).Value
            If .Cells(17, "M").Value = "PASS" Then Exit Sub
        Next cell
    End With    
    MsgBox "No available bearing." 
End Sub
```